# ListView.setAdapter causes force close in JIFace print

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, forceclose

My problem is that lv.SetAdapter causes force close in this code always, but when I use it in onCreate or ... it works. I need to setAdapter after JIFace -> Print processes, so what can I do ? Thank you ! :)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        webView = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(iface, "droid");
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }

    JIFace iface = new JIFace();
    WebViewClient client = new MyClient();

    class MyClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url); 
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.droid.print(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);");
        }
    }

    class JIFace {
        public void print(String data) {
            // here application do some processes and then creates an AdapterView with name aa
                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    // the problem is it's not possible to setAdapter here... It's not important what's the ArrayAdapter...
                lv.setAdapter(aa);
        }
    }
```

and my LogCat :

```
01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4056)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:722)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:771)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4109)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8621)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8572)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1716)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:502)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:442)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at com.example.MainActivity$JIFace.print(MainActivity.java:72)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:280)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1840)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1700(WebViewCore.java:55)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1162)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:728)

01-17 11:21:33.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28906):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

PROBLEM SOLVED:

I've just used :

```
Handler handler;
Runnable r;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Handler = new H
r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // create ArrayAdapter here
                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
                lv.setAdapter(aa);
    }
};
    webView = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(iface, "droid");
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
}

JIFace iface = new JIFace();
WebViewClient client = new MyClient();

class MyClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url); 
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.droid.print(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);");
    }
}

class JIFace {
    public void print(String data) {
        // here application do some processes and then creates an AdapterView with name aa
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
// the problem is it's not possible to setAdapter here... It's not important what's the ArrayAdapter...
            handler.post(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show here code, How are you creating ArrayAdapter instance??

Comment: Ascorbin: Added. Thank you. :)

Comment: vishesh chandra : It's not important, i've used :    ArrayAdapter<string> aa;
aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al); // al is an arraylist and i've used this code in onCreate, too. It worked in onCreate ! and exactly the same code, doesn't work here !

Comment: Instead of **this use YourActivity.this** and you are calling print method from Non UI thread, call it from UI thread.

Comment: CalledFromWrongThreadException is caused by updating the UI from a background thread. Is there some thread/AsyncTask code that you're not showing us?

Comment: Vishesh chandra : no i've used MainActivity.this in my code truely ! But the problem... :( Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: NigelK : no but i think print of JIFace is like a background thread waiting for WebView to load page and it's source... so, how can I create ArrayList here and show it in UI ? ( automatically without a button or ... ) Thank You. :)